# How do I mount a jailbroken iPhone as a volume in Lion?

Tags: iphone, macos, filesystem

In Snow Leopard I was using [this utility](http://code.google.com/p/iphonedisk/) (it uses MacFuse) to mount my iPhone as a volume upon its connection. Worked very well, and I could browse my jailbroken iPhone's files easily and drag/drop over themes like on a normal HD.

Since OS X Lion, it doesn't appear to be working. Are there any un-obtrusive tweaks to achieve this again? Or does anyone know how to get the MacFuse filesystem working on OS X Lion?

Comment: I usually use an FTP app to SSH into it. Until MacFuse comes to Lion.

Comment: Ta, but as far as I remember I used Cyberduck. http://ihackthatifone.com/ssh-tutorial-with-cyberduck/

Answer (score -1):

Phone Disk ain't free, but would be a good choice: http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/

Comment: That has a menubar icon that is uglier then all get out. Plus I don't need another app running constantly.

Comment: Their website provides no indication that it works under Lion (listing the requirements as 10.5 and 10.6).